# Brackets: Autocomplete for Phaser framework

Tags: autocomplete, phaser-framework, adobe-brackets

Does a plugin for Brackets exists in order to have autocomplete for `Phaser` ? So far I found nothing but the documentation of Phaser for Brackets.
I am looking for what `Sublime` has or `WebStorm` (I use `Brackets` because it has a server and it's easier for me to run the program)

Comment: I have not seen anything similar in Brackets, however I have tried it in Visual Studio [https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/101278/intellisense-with-phaserjs-library-in-visual-studio-code] and recently I saw something similar in Sublime Text [https://phaser.io/news/2016/02/sublime-text-phaser-auto-complete-plugin]

Comment: Wiat, what? More than 50MB for a text editor app?